# Stackexchange.Redis support for XX|NX|CH?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Does stackexchange.redis support the NX and other related switches from [ZADD](http://redis.io/commands/ZADD)?
I had a look in the documentation, unit tests and code but couldn't find any reference to it. Would be great if someone could shed some light on how to implement this if its not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not implemented on the latest stable version of SE.Redis.

But you can still use *ScriptEvaluate* to execute arbitrary redis commands, for example:

```
var ctx = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("...");
var db = ctx.GetDatabase();
db.ScriptEvaluate("return redis.call('zadd', KEYS[1], unpack(ARGV))", 
    new RedisKey[] { "key" }, 
    new RedisValue[] { "NX", 12.34, "member" });
```

Also you can use [CachingFramework.Redis](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis#cachingframeworkredis) library that is built on top of SE.Redis, since the SortedSet commands already handles the NX/XX switches, for example:

```
var context = new CachingFramework.Redis.Context();
var sset = context.Collections.GetRedisSortedSet<string>("key");
sset.Add(12.34, "member", When.NotExists);
```